# Hadoop local job directory get deleted before job is completed on task nodes

Tags: hadoop

We are having a strange issue in our Hadoop cluster. We have noticed that some of our jobs fail with the with a file not found exception[see below]. Basically the files in the "attempt_*" directory and the directory itself are getting deleted while the task is still being run on the host. Looking through some of the hadoop documentation I see that the job directory gets wiped out when it gets a KillJobAction however I am not sure why it gets wiped out while the job is still running.

My question is what could be deleting it while the job is running? Any thoughts or pointers on how to debug this would be helpful.

Thanks!

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: <dir>/hadoop/mapred/local_data/taskTracker/<user>/jobcache/job_201211030344_15383/attempt_201211030344_15383_m_000169_0/output/spill29.out (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$TrackingFileInputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.open(RawLocalFileSystem.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$Segment.init(Merger.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$Segment.access$100(Merger.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Merger.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Merger.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.merge(Merger.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.mergeParts(MapTask.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:765)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
```

Comment: No. We thought it was that but the files themselves don't exist.

Comment: Where do the files come from?  My pattern is to always delete the output folder before running a job (I think you have to). Could that be happening here?

Comment: It is not the output folder of the map task, it is the intermediate folder that the MapTask creates when it is running. There are temporary files in here that the map task needs while it is running. These files get deleted mysteriously.

Comment: Has this ever worked?  I'm wondering if HDFS is propagating a delete when one mapper is done but another mapper is still running.  I promise that's my last guess. Sorry.

Comment: How do I confirm that? There is nothing in the logs that would signal a delete. Also it would be silly for it to proactively delete the directories without notifications..

Comment: It may be due to that Hadoop cannot create the *output/spill29.out* at the first place - permission denied?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and found that this Permission error was caused due to the hadoop program not being able to create or access the files.

Are the files being created inside the hdfs or on any local file system.
If they are on a local file system, then try setting permissions to that folder, if they are on the hdfs folder then try setting permissions to that folder.

If you are running it on ubuntu then

try running

chmod -R a=rwx //hadoop/mapred/local_data/taskTracker//jobcache/job_201211030344_15383/attempt_201211030344_15383_m_000169_0/output/